# Does any divide-and-conquer algorithm use recursion

Tags: algorithm, divide-and-conquer

I am arguing with a fellow student, as he wants to convince me that there is a possibility that a divide-and-conquer algorithm can be implemented without the use of recursion.

Is this truly the case?

Comment: Would using a user-defined stack to store arguments still count as recursion, although technically there is no recursive call?

Comment: The question is what you *consider* recursion. If it's only about the implementation and you define recursion using something like the C language in the naive way, you could get by without recursion. Otherwise, my opinion is that by definition all divide-and-conquer *algorithms* are recursive.

Answer (score 7):

Any algorithm that can be implemented with recursion can also be implemented non-recursively.

> Recursion and iteration are equally expressive: recursion can be replaced by iteration with an explicit stack, while iteration can be replaced with tail recursion. Which approach is preferable depends on the problem under consideration and the language used.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29#Recursion_versus_iteration

Answer (score 0):

There's an important thing to understand: using or not recursion is an implementation decision. Recursion is not necessary to add computing power (at least not to a Turing complete language). Look up "Tail recursion" for an easy example of how to transform a recursive function to a non recursive one (in the case of a divide-et-impera algorithm you can remove at most 1 of the recursive calls with this method).

A function/algorithm that is computable with recursion is computable also without it. What matters is if the language with which you implement the algorithm is Turing complete or not.

Let's make an example. The mergesort algorithm can be implemented also in a non recursive way using a queue as an auxiliary data structure to keep track of the various merges.

Comment: You can even do merge sort without a queue if you work bottom-up.

Comment: Absolutely! I made that particular example because it is more similar to the recursive version (you split the array in one-item arrays, pop two partitions at a time, merge them, and then push the result in the queue - and repeat until only the result remains in the queue - instead of making the recursive calls on the original array in order to split it and merge the partitions on the return). Then there are a million ways to implement the algorithm obviously.